# How to extract the top-level of protocols into the csv file by using tshark command?

Tags: protocols, wireshark

Here is what I tried:
tshark -r test.pcap -T fields -e ip.proto > output.csv

But this can only show all the protocols in the csv files.

I want to show only the top level of protocol numbers such as 6(TCP), 17(UDP), 1(ICMP) etc.

Any idea please. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use -R to apply a display filter: `tshark -r test.pcap -R "port 17 or port 6"`